# Value of type 'Text' has no member 'lineHeightMultiple' error message

Tags: swiftui, deprecated, line-spacing, attributedstring

I want to decrease line height for Text elements in my SwiftUI project. I use the following code and it works fine:

`Text("Hello world!\nHello world!")._lineHeightMultiple(0.83)`

The problem with the modifier is that it is deprecated and I get the warning:
[image]

The warning suggests to use lineHeightMultiple instead but when I follow the recommendation I get the error:
[image]

I tried to use lineHeightMultiple in Xcode 13.2.1 and Xcode 14.1 but I get the same warnings and errors.

I tried to find a documentation regarding this method but it seems the documentation doesn't exist. Xcode just opens a file which doesn't have such method. I tried to install Xcode 12 to find the documentation there but it is not compatible with my MacOS.

I tried to change line height using AttributedString but it doesn't support NSParagraphStyle.

I tried to use lineSpacing modifier but it doesn't support negative values.

I tried to use UILabel or UITextView with UIViewRepresentation but the layout doesn't always work as expected.

I tried to use TextEditor with Introspect library to access UITextView's attributedText parameter but there is a similar issue with layout.

Comment: Are you developing for more than one platform? Then the problem could be that it is not available at one of them.

Comment: I develop only for iPhones.

Comment: I've found a bug report related to the issue https://openradar.appspot.com/FB9842474.

Comment: That is also a non-public API. Anytime you see a modifier, or other element, preceded by an "_" from Apple, it is non-public. Here, for a reason as it is not working properly.